# bigquery: query data JSON

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have an JSON objet withs ID / keys.

Within those keys is the result of each analysis of each ID.

```
"raw_result":{"3117092402546":true,"3110924118082":false,"3117014230082":true,"3171295576130":true}
```

I need to extract that information in some way that allows me to make queries later. For example: an array of data.

result I expected

```
**document_id     id                   result**
918348            3117092402546        true
918348            3110924118082        false    
918348            3117014230082        true
918348            3171295576130        true
```

could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"raw_result":{"3117092402546":true,"3110924118082":false,"3117014230082":"true","3171295576130":true}}', '$.raw_result') json
)
SELECT k AS id, v AS result
  FROM sample,
       UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys(json)) k WITH OFFSET ki,
       UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_values(json)) v WITH OFFSET vi
 WHERE ki = vi
;
```

[image]

And for the UDFs I've used, you can check them on below site:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community

Comment: I tried this: ```WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.Url.')  as Url,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.raw_result.') json
  from table
)

SELECT
  k AS id, 
  v AS result

FROM sample,

       UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys(json)) k WITH OFFSET ki,
       UNNEST(bqutil.fn.json_extract_values(json)) v WITH OFFSET vi

WHERE ki = vi
;```. Error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at UDF$1(STRING) line 2, columns 16-17

Comment: I guess `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.raw_result.') json`  returns `NULL`.  Try `JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.raw_result') json` instead of `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`.

Comment: I've updated the query in my answer to extract `raw_result` AS a json object, not a scalar value.  It will work.